# Error: [] cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused docker

Tags: docker, curl, docker-compose

I'm using this for my local environment for WordPress [docker-lemp](https://gitlab.com/paveljame/docker-lemp), problem is that I'm getting error

```
The REST API is one way WordPress, and other applications, communicate with the server. One example is the block editor screen, which relies on this to display, and save, your posts and pages.

The REST API request failed due to an error.
Error: [] cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

Is there any way to fix it?